# How do I print a table horizontally rather than vertically like it is done here?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

this is what I have tried, the table is printed vertically with unit and percent like I want them but all of it is vertical. I want unit and percent vertical, but the next unit and percent to be horizontal to the last unit and percent, but also vertical in their respect

this is what I want it to look like:

`unit` `unit` `unit` `unit` `unit`

`perc` `perc` `perc` `perc` `perc`

```
$table = '';
    $table .= '<table border="1">';
     foreach ($gradebook as $row) 
    { 
        $table .=  '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td>' . $row['unit'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';
        $table .=  '<tr>';
        $table .= '<td>' . $row['percent'] . '</td>';
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
print($table);
```

this is my query in case it is needed

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

  $gradebook[]=array('unit'=>$row['unit'],'percent'=>$row['percent']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll simply have to iterate through the array twice:

```
$table .= '<table border="1">';
$table .=  '<tr>';
foreach ($gradebook as $row) 
{ 
    $table .= '<td>' . $row['unit'] . '</td>';
}
$table .= '</tr>';
$table .=  '<tr>';
foreach ($gradebook as $row) 
{ 
    $table .= '<td>' . $row['percent'] . '</td>';
}
$table .= '</tr>';
$table .= '</table>';
```

Thus, composing a row (`tr`) for each field.